# FileSystemWatcher: remote network issue

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I've got issues with this task.

I have a client-server application for synchronizing files in certain folders. The local client runs on Windows 7 and server is on Windows server and I need a local desktop application that would check the file changes on the server and to notify these changes. I've played a bit with the FileSystemWatcher class, but it seems to work only on mapped drives or local machines either. It has to be somehing like http://server.com/watched_directory.

Is there another way, how to reach the point?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. `FileSystemWatcher` just works on local or mapped folders and do not work over http protocol.

Anyways, you can to write an application which uses `FileSystemWatcher` and run it on your server with a WCF interface to your client on Windows 7 machine can interact with data collected by first application. So, it will be more like a client/server application, but seems to fit your scenario.